# Core Data - Relationship

Tags: core-data, save

Please let me know how to save objects through relationship.
If I have two entities like Notes , Category entity
Note is one to one for Category.
Category Many to one for Notes.

How to save , if we have Category context to Notes..

Please provide me some inputs.

How to save through sets. It would be greatful

---

I have Employee and Department entities. Department has one to many relationship with Employee. Employee has one to one relationship with Department. I want save object of employee entity using department entity.

Each time I have create new Object for Employee –

```
import UIKit
import CoreData
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var container: NSPersistentContainer? = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate)?.persistentContainer
    let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
    var empSet = NSSet()
    var empS = Set<EmployeeExample>()
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        var context:NSManagedObjectContext = (container?.viewContext)!
        let dept = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObject(forEntityName: "Department", into: context) as! Department
        let emp = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObject(forEntityName: "Employee", into: (container?.viewContext)!) as! Employee
        emp.firstName = "YYYY"
        emp.lastName = "HHHHHHH"
        empS.insert(emp)
        print("Count of Emp SSSS Set == \(empS.count)")
        let emp1 = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObject(forEntityName: "Employee", into: (container?.viewContext)!) as! Employee
        emp1.firstName = "RRRRR"
        emp1.lastName = "YYYYY"
        empS.insert(emp1)
        empSet.addingObjects(from: empS)
        dept.deptName = "CCC"
        print("Count of Emp SSSS Set == \(empS.count)")
        print("Count of Emp Set == \(empSet.count)")
        dept.addToEmp(empSet)
        do {
            try appDelegate.saveContext()
            print("Saved -------------")
        }catch {
            print("Error")
        }
    }



}
```

Comment: Apple provides detailed information on this subject, for example the [Creating Managed Object Relationships](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/HowManagedObjectsarerelated.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001075-CH17-SW1) section of their Core Data Programming Guide. Is there something specific you don't understand or are having trouble with?

Comment: Thank you.  I have doubt in these lines anEmployee.department = newDepartment     How to get the newDepartment value.   Whether i have to declare   let newDepartment = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObject(forEntityName: "Department", into: (container?.viewContext)!) as! Department.      I am stuck in these lines .Please help me

Comment: I have Employee and Department entities. Department has  one to many relationship with Employee. Employee has one to one relationship with Department. I want save object of employee entity using department entity.

Comment: import CoreData
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    var container: NSPersistentContainer? = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate)?.persistentContainer
     let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate

Comment: var empSet = NSSet()
     var empS = Set<EmployeeExample>()

Comment: override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        var context:NSManagedObjectContext = (container?.viewContext)!

Comment: let dept = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObject(forEntityName: "Department", into: context) as! Department    
        let emp = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObject(forEntityName: "Employee", into: (container?.viewContext)!) as! Employee
        emp.firstName = "YYYY"
        emp.lastName = "HHHHHHH"
        empS.insert(emp)        
                  let emp1 = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObject(forEntityName: " Employee ", into: (container?.viewContext)!) as! Employee

Comment: emp1.firstName = "RRRRR"
        emp1.lastName = "YYYYY"
          empS.insert(emp1)
         empSet.addingObjects(from: empS)
        dept.deptName = "CCC" 
           dept.addToEmp(empSet)
      do {
            try appDelegate.saveContext()
                    }catch   { }
}

Comment: My Question is  Each time I have create new Object for Employee

Comment: If you are going to add code to your question, you can edit your original question and add it there. It's much more readable when it's formatted properly, and it's easier to see the code in the context of the question rather than down in the comments.

Answer (score 1):

> I have doubt in these lines anEmployee.department = newDepartment How to get the newDepartment value. Whether i have to declare let newDepartment = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObject(forEntityName: "Department", into: (container?.viewContext)!) as! Department.

The `Department` object here is whatever object should be related to that specific `Employee` object. How you get it depends on how your app works, but you probably want to do one of these:

1. If the employee belongs to a new department that doesn't already exist in your app, you create a new instance of `Department` and assign that object as `anEmployee.department`.
2. If the employee belongs to a department that already exists in your app, you use an already existing `Department`. You probably get that by fetching `Department` objects from Core Data-- either with `NSFetchRequest` or by using an `NSFetchedResultsController`.